# Add a namespace prefix to the tags of the default name space of an XML document from the shell

Tags: xml, namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have a SVG file, which is an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <defs
     id="defs2">
  <!-- a lot of stuff --> </defs>
  <!-- more stuff like -->
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <!-- etc... -->
</svg>
```

I want to add the svg: prefix to all the tags corresponding to the default namespace in order to get next output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg:svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
  <svg:defs
     id="defs2">
  <!-- a lot of stuff--> </svg:defs>
  <!-- more stuff like -->
  <svg:metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </svg:metadata>
  <!-- etc... -->
</svg:svg>
```

I am sure this is possible in one or few command lines from the shell using **xmllint** and/or **xmlstarlet** but I can't manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you prepared to give the new Gizmo tool in Saxon 10.0 a try? If so:

Invoke Gizmo with a command like:

```
java -cp saxon-he-10.0.jar:jline-2.9.jar net.sf.saxon.Gizmo
```

Then enter the sub-commands

```
load x/y/z/input.xml
namespace svg http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
rename /*:svg as "svg:svg"
save x/y/z/output.xml
quit
```

Documentation is at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!gizmo

Be aware that this is very new software (only released for the first time on Monday) so you're on the bleeding edge...

Comment: Interesting, but I guess I don't have to issue `rename /*:svg as "svg:svg"` which seems at first glance to change only the root element `<svg>` into `<svg:svg>` with the corresponding closing tag. My purpose is to change all the tags from the default namespace into tags prefixed by `svg:`. Or don't I understand the `rename` operation correctly?

Comment: I didn't install the software because I solved my problem in another way, but I am interested to monitor Gizmo. Could it be that the `rename` command I have to issue would look like `rename //*[not(contains (name(), ":"))] as concat ("svg:", name())`?

Comment: You've changed the question, so yes, that changes the answer! You could also try `rename //svg:* as concat('svg:', local-name())` which would rename every element in the SVG namespace whatever prefix it uses.

Comment: I didn't change the question. I only added more code to show what I mean.